# Trying to separate dimensions of my xyz coordinates nodes to a 3D NetworkX graph

Tags: python, graph, 3d, plotly, networkx

I am new to Python and I tried to make a 3D network graph using a csv file, with NetworkX and Plotly. I used **Spring3D** function and tried to separate dimensions from the array which was generated like in a tutorial I saw on Deepnote, but I am unable to do it probably because my nodes data aren't read like integers, however I specified the nodetype **int** in my arguments... or maybe because I have to convert my data to matrix or array.(see my screens below)

When I call one of my nodes it sends me back a Key Error, but it works when I call it like string `spring_3D ['4']`. I don't know if this problem is linked to the fact that I can't assign my coordinates to my nodes but I suppose. I really don't know and I tried so many ways (like using different ways of importing my data with **csv.reader** and **with open** I was able to see my nodes like an integer with this method `np.array([[int(e) for e in row] for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')])` but it didn't work at the next step.

I also tried to add nodes manually but unsuccessfully. I used the read.adjlist method but it's probably the same thing. I think the answer is probably pretty obvious.

I work on python 3.6 with Jupyter notebook and Anaconda

```
G = nx.read_adjlist('clean Passerelles-mentales final 1bisfinal.csv', delimiter = ',', nodetype = int )

spring_pos = nx.spring_layout(G, seed=3) 
    nx.draw_networkx(G, with_labels = True)

spring_3D = nx.spring_layout(g,dim=3, seed=18)

x_nodes = [spring_3D[i][0] for i in range(Num_nodes)]# x-coordinates of nodes
y_nodes = [spring_3D[i][1] for i in range(Num_nodes)]# y-coordinates
z_nodes = [spring_3D[i][2] for i in range(Num_nodes)]# z-coordinates
```

I received a Key Error

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

An example of what I am trying to do:
https://deepnote.com/@deepnote/3D-network-visualisations-using-plotly-oYxeN6UXSye_3h_ulKV2Dw

Comment: If you replace the `for i in range(Num_nodes)` with `for i in G` it should work.

Comment: @Sparky05 Thanks a lot for your answer! Your help is precious, but unfortunately, i m afraid it resolve only a part of the problem, but there is progress !
In fact, i get a Key Error [1] this time... 

```x_nodes = [spring_3D[i][0] for i in G]# x-coordinates of nodes
y_nodes = [spring_3D[i][1] for i in G]# y-coordinates
z_nodes = [spring_3D[i][2] for i in G]# z-coordinates```

((Sorry in advance for my Bad level in python...I'm going to learn))

Comment: I just found the answer, I simply had to specify the nodetype before the 3D scattering in the **nx.draw_networkx**  function arguments like that :

```G = nx.read_adjlist('clean Passerelles-mentales final 1bisfinal.csv', delimiter = ',', nodetype = int )
spring_pos = nx.spring_layout(G, seed=3) 
nx.draw_networkx(G, with_labels = True, nodetype = int)```

And of course, like you said @Sparky05 replace the range by G, thanks a lot !!!

Comment: And thanks to @JasonAller for the corrections, I'm really bad in English (I am French)